# Creating a multipage, template-like report with sql repoting servives

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, service, pagination, reporting

I hope I'm not repeating someone elses question but I'm pretty new to SQL Reporting Services and am trying to build something that I'm not sure can be done:
I have a dataset with around 20 fields representing columns in a table. I would like to emulate a .docx report in which each of these rows represents a page in the report. It doesnt matter if the result is a word file or a pdf, as long as the formatting is pretty similar, and I can produce around 3000 pages where one page represents one row in the dataset.

I'm sure it can be done, I'm just not sure where to start!!

EDIT: TO give a better idea of what I'm trying to do, I guess you could look at  it as something like a word mail-merge sort of setup, where I fill a predefined page 3000 times with indivual data..

Thanks in advnace for any help or tips!

Michael

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to split into pages.
Go to tablix properties > General (sparator) > PageBreak, here you can do whatever you want example: BreakLocation; ResetPageNumber;
Also, You can give a page name or repeat the column headers.

Tell me if it is what do you want.

Comment: Hi Ricardo,

thanks for your quick reply. As you wrote this I started looking at lists which seems to be doing pretty much what I want it to. Due to the fact that the cell widths and height are not the same throughout the page I'm not sure a table (tablix in report builder??) will do the trick. 
Putting text boxes in a List seems to do it, there will just be a lot of formatting and alignmet involved :)

Comment: I said tablix, but it is what you have choosen!